# How to select the rating bar in List Adapter in android?

Tags: android-listview

Eventhough this question has been asked by users many number of times,I am not able to solve my problem by going through all the posts.I have used list view in android.And to the listview i have added the rating bar,text view and some other child items.I am able to select only the entire list item.I want to select the individual list items.I will paste the code which i have tried.

```
        public class ReviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
           private final Context context;
           private final String[] values;
           public ReviewAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
                super(context,R.layout.activity_reviewlist,values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_reviewlist, parent,false);
                 TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                 TextView tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                 TextView tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                 TextView tv4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                 TextView tv5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                 RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
                 ratingbar.setIsIndicator(true);
                 ImageView im1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                 tv1.setText(values[position]);
                 String s = values[position];
                 if(s.equals("Speech for Presentation")){
                    tv2.setText("07 th May 2011 22:30");
                    tv3.setText("05:30");
                    tv4.setText("Attempts");
                    tv5.setText("5");
                 }
                 else if(s.equals("Slide Show Presentation")){
                    tv2.setText("08 th May 2011 21:15");
                    tv3.setText("04:12");
                    tv4.setText("Attempts");
                    tv5.setText("7");
                 }
                 else if(s.equals("Seminar Presentation")){
                    tv2.setText("09 th May 2011 10:15");
                    tv3.setText("08:26");
                    tv4.setText("Attempts");
                    tv5.setText("9");
                 }
                 else if(s.equals("Training Speech")){
                    tv2.setText("10 th May 2011 9:16");
                    tv3.setText("09:26");
                    tv4.setText("Attempts");
                    tv5.setText("3");
                 }

                 else{
                    tv2.setText("12 th May 2011 10:10");
                    tv3.setText("19:26");
                    tv4.setText("Attempts");
                    tv5.setText("7");
                 }
                return rowView;
            }

        }
```

And now i am going to paste my list activity here

```
       public class ReviewActivity extends ListActivity {

      static final String[] reviews = new String[] {"Speech for Presentation","Slide Show Presentation","Seminar Presentation","Training Speech","Promoting the product"};  

       protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            //get selected items
            String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ReviewAdapter(this, reviews));

        }


    }
```

Lastly iam pasting the xml which i have tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:src="@drawable/timer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```